# Background color sticking in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, internet-explorer-11

At first, I was trying to make it so :hover over a div element would change the background color. I did this with just simple CSS. It worked in Chrome and some earlier IE versions I've checked. With IE 11 though, when my mouse leaves the div, the hover background color stayed there.

So then I used jQuery to, on hover, add a class on hover and remove the class on mouseleave (and in the CSS file I associated the hover background color with this class). I used console.log to check that it was in these parts properly, and they were there, but removeClass('class-name') just is not actually removing the class in IE 11 for some reason.

I tried to use setClass and classList.remove/add too and could not remove the added class. Even though console.log showed that I was right there in the code that would do this.

So then I tried to, instead of adding/removing a class, just change the background color directly with hover events in jQuery, like $('div.target').css('background-color', 'color'). This worked the first two times. On hover, it changed to the hover background color, then leaving, it changed to the other color. But then I couldn't hover over the div again to get the hover color to come back.

Any tips or knowledge about quirks that could cause these issues?

Comment: Did you try to use `.blur(function() { });` instead of `.mouseleave(function() { });` ?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet use JQuery `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` to perform a `background-color` changing. Works with IE 9+.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L0Lhhhon/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDiv myDiv-red">

</div>
```

**CSS**
.myDiv
{
    height : 30px;
    width : 30px;
}

```
.myDiv-red
{
    background-color : red;
}

.myDiv-green
{
    background-color : green;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $(".myDiv").mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).removeClass("myDiv-red").addClass("myDiv-green");
    });

    $(".myDiv").mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).removeClass("myDiv-green").addClass("myDiv-red"); 
    });
});
```